# Can't load CSV into MySQL: Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns

Tags: mysql, docker, csv

I spun a container with the `mysql` image. I am trying to load a CSV.

It looks sort of like this but with more rows. It is located in `/local/data/af_bases.csv` within the container. You can get a copy of the file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xaviermerino/nomad-jobs/master/covid19/mysql/data/af_bases.csv).

```
Tinker AFB,Oklahoma,9y69rzbsh9mz,-1
Andrews AFB,Maryland,dqckf8m8ry2c,-1
Grissom AFB,Indiana,dp4xrf0ufvjd,-1
```

I create a database `geolocations`. And then I want to run the following:

```sql
USE geolocations;

CREATE TABLE bases( 
name varchar(255), 
state varchar(255), 
geohash varchar(255),
confirmed float,
timestamp timestamp not null default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
);

LOAD DATA INFILE '/local/data/af_bases.csv' INTO TABLE bases 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

However, I get the following:

```
ERROR 1261 (01000): Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
```

I have tried enclosing the data in double quotations and doing `ENCLOSED BY '"'` but it doesn't seem to like it either way.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has 5 columns, the CSV only has 4 fields in each row.

The CSV is missing the `timestamp` column. If you want that to get the default value instead of taking it from the CSV, you need to list the columns explicitly in the `LOAD DATA` statement. The default is to fill in all the columns of the table.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/local/data/af_bases.csv' 
INTO TABLE bases (name, state, geohash, confirmed)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks, it was similar to that. It ended up being: 
```LOAD DATA INFILE '/local/data/af_bases.csv' 
INTO TABLE bases
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(name, state, geohash, confirmed);```

Answer (score 0):

[Error 1261](https://www.fromdual.com/de/mysql-error-codes-and-messages-1250-1299) is a mismatch of columns and data i.e. having only 4 rows and 5 columns.